# Why did Unix use slash as the directory separator?

Tags: unix, multics

The Unix designers came from the GE/MIT Multics project, and Multics inspired some Unix features. In particular, Multics has a hierarchical filesystem, and so does Unix.

On Multics, pathnames were of the form:

```
>dir1>dir2>dir3>filename
```

but Unix uses

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/filename
```

Is there any documentation of why they chose that syntax instead of copying Multics?

I thought of this because `>` has become common in modern day displays of other hierarchical paths, such as breadcrumb lists in web applications and CSS child selectors.

Multics also used `<` to represent upward motion in relative pathnames, e.g. Unix

```
../../foo/bar
```

would be

```
<<foo>bar
```

This has a nice symmetry that `../` lacks, although `..` has the advantage of being implemented in the filesystem itself (it's simply a link to the parent directory). On Multics, `<` is implemented in a user-mode library that canonicalizes pathnames before being passed to the kernel.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4686/where-do-command-line-switches-originate-from

Comment: @Raffzahn I saw that, as well as questions about why DOS used backslash instead of slash. The relationship with this question is very tenuous.

Comment: See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103471/86440) on [Unix.SE].

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80152/discussion-on-question-by-barmar-why-did-unix-use-slash-as-the-directory-separat).

Comment: As a personal opinion, moderators moving conversations to chat is the worst feature of SE.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Comments are not for extended discussion of moderator actions, this discussion should be moved to chat :)

Comment: @Barmar: technically I  wasn't discussing, but rather stating an opinion. But yes, the restrictive definition of "comment" is equally bad. Some of the best content in SE I've seen in the comments.

Comment: I'd switch from > to / to save pressing the shift key so often.

Comment: @TimLocke You get used to it. But that reminds me that Lisp Machine keyboards had extra keys with unshifted `(` and `)`, since those were needed so much. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Space-cadet.jpg/1200px-Space-cadet.jpg

Answer (score 65):

Primordial Unix on the PDP-7 was [in many ways very different](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/hist.html) from what we know today.  Directories existed but were very awkward to use; in practice most work was done in a single directory.  Most importantly, paths did not yet exist.  What was implemented early on though was a simple syntax for IO redirection on the commandline.  Whereas on Multics one would have to say<sup>1</sup>

```
iocall attach user_output file xx
list
iocall attach user_output syn user_i/o
```

on Unix one could simply say

```
ls >xx
```

STDIN could similarly be redirected.

When paths were eventually implemented (on PDP-11 Unix) `<` and `>` were already in use so a new syntax was needed.  I am unaware of the precise reason `/` was chosen for this; it's likely that its convenient location on Teletype Model 37<sup>2</sup> terminals was a consideration.

<sup>1</sup> `iocall` was an 'author-maintained' (i.e. non-standard) command.

<sup>2</sup> The Model 37 could easily be adapted to handle mathematical symbols; this was important since early Unix was intended to be used for technical writing (see e.g. `roff`).  The `/` is next to right-shift on the Model 37, same as on most modern keyboards.

Comment: I might be misreading but: is the general idea that redirecting input/output in a single operator a really exciting notion/feature for Unix, and that angle brackets were the logical/practical best operator for this, and thus they had to come up with a new token for directory paths?

Comment: Or is it more like redirection was this cool thing they implemented with no thought at all for directories/paths (because they were trivial/clunky in other systems) and later when they wanted to adopt them they were like "crap, we've already used `>` for this other thing, so we need a new token for paths"?

Comment: @Anthony That's the impression I've gotten.  The PDP-7 system that Unix was created on was _very_ limited in terms of resources.  Full paths weren't really needed until the arrival of larger disks (when the PDP-11 was acquired) and the cost (in resources) was a bit high for marginal return.  Since directories were inodes from the beginning it made sense to chain a sequence of directories and an optional file (all inodes) together into a path.  The choice of `/` to delimit the sequence was, as I stated above, likely a matter of convenience.

Comment: @Anthony Note that on Unix there is no reason to have special syntax for 'parent directory'; a simple `../` will suffice.  (The inode listed for the `..` entry in the current directory's file/directory list is the parent directory's inode).  Unix filesystems were inode-based from the beginning.

Comment: +1 to "its convenient location on Teletype Model 37 terminals".  Much of early Unix syntax and commands was about keyboard simplification, since apparently the keys on those terminals were pretty stiff.

Answer (score 3):

There were other hierarchical file systems around.
The Burroughs operating systems used (and as Unisys, still do) `/`
Although in a someone clunky way:

```
(PHYS212)ACOUSTICS/RAYS/OUTPUT ON USERPACK
 ^^^^ usercode                    ^^^^^^^ device
```

MS-DOS and Windows also accept `/` in file paths, in addition to
`\`.  It is the command language where this does not work;
system calls are fine.

EMAS-3 used `{username:]{groupname.}*localname{_partname}`
where username is up to 6 letters and digits and the others
are up to 11, groups are basically directories except for not
being files, and parts have to do with "partitioned data sets"
(think ar(1) archives but usefully nested).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#History) claims that Multics introduced the hierarchical file system. It was publicized at a conference in 1965. When did Burroughs add it?

Comment: Did MS-DOS 2.0 (which added directories) support `/` out of the box? I have the impression that this was added on later, when Unix had become more popular.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, and if you use the SWITCHAR CONFIG.SYS variable to change the default command line switch character from `/` to something else (eg. `-`), you could even use `/` in directory names with the standard MS-DOS commands. This was a feature that only MS-DOS 2.x supported.

Comment: Mind you, the reason MS-DOS 2.0 had SWITCHAR was because Microsoft wanted to move the DOS userbase over to XENIX- their variety of Unix. This is the same reason why MS-DOS 2.0 supported a filesystem structure with a similar separator, and a semblance of file permissions. Ironically, these changes were exactly what made people comfortable sticking with a DOS instead of moving to a Unixey.

Answer (score 2):

[DTSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmouth_Time_Sharing_System), developed around the same time as Multics, and influenced by it, used `:` as the directory separator. A leading `:` was used for absolute paths (starting at the root directory). There was no easy way to indicate "parent directory" (Unix/Linux `..`) — programs that needed to walk the directory tree had to keep track of things themselves.

Comment: Coincidentally, DTSS was the second OS I used, after TSS/8 on a PDP-8 (this was around 1978). I had a friend in high school whose older brother was a sysadmin for a company that had a DTSS system, and he created a guest account for us to use.

Comment: This is interesting, but how does it answer the question? Please read the [tour], and then [edit] your answer.

Comment: Classic MacOS also uses a colon, I guess because it makes something close to semantic sense, unlike a slash which in regular English suggests alternatives.

Comment: So what influence did Dartmouth have on the decision to use `/` for Unix's path separator?

Comment: Interestingly, it turns out that ":" was used as the path separator in Multics at an early point in the project's development.  See [this paper describing the initial development of the multics file system](http://www.multicians.org/fjcc4.html).  It looks very much as though Bell Labs may have withdrawn from Multics development at approximately the same time as the path separator was being changed in any case, so it seems that the Unix developers may not have had much chance to become familiar with the Multics syntax described in the question in any case.

Comment: Interestingly, `:` and `/` are both used as separators for dates (`YY/MM/DD`) and time.